# Vimeo APi, Private Links and Password protected videos

Tags: node.js, vimeo-api

first of all i want to say that i did searched a lot before i wrote here but
none of the answers did answered my questions so that brings me here.

I have created an app on vimeo api, i have also created an access token will full permissions,on the authentication area it says this:

```
Personal access tokens
The following tokens are authenticated to Amit Shadadi.
```

i then put it in my node js code.

Now when i try to get a video with the security of private link only - i get nothing, 
when i switch to everyone -  i get the video's url.

when i try to use password - i don't get the video url (what am i missing?)

So i can't get video with private link and i can't get video that is protected by password, so what can i do if i want to get the video url but hide it from vimeo?

i want the video url to be reviled only when my api request it or when i enter with my account to vimeo console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the wrong token somehow. Troubleshooting would require sharing sensitive information (tokens, video links, etc.) so I suggest contacting Vimeo for support:

https://vimeo.com/help/contact